# Microsoft word, How to change lowercase to uppercase, and uppercase to bigger uppercase

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

In Microsoft word, how to change lowercase to uppercase, and uppercase to bigger uppercase.
Like this:

[image]

Comment: I found this format in a .docx. I chose the "Hello World!" and changed to different fonts. Fonts changed but the behavior was still the same. I want to know how the author of the .docx made it that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the text > right click > Font > Effects > Small Caps